# User does not see "check out" message in SharePoint aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-server, check-out

Normally, when the page is check out to other user (i.e. User A), when other users (User B) open this page, there is a yellow section message to inform that "page is check out to ...". (Refer to below image)
[image]

But recently, users inform that there is no check out message above the check out page.
How can we bring the check out message back in SharePoint aspx page?

Comment: Modern page or classic page?

Comment: Classic page sp 2016